# How to change the color of a Canvas Object Periodically?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, colors, android-canvas

I have this class named GameView for making a shooter game but I want that the cannon object of shooter class which draws a cannon at bottom , should change its color after 4 seconds as part of my game project so I used Timer class to work on it but it didn't work it only changes color when I moves cannon and redraws the cannon on screen...

Some Useful Details and code below

1.Gameview Class--> Draws a gameboard also includes cannon object of shooter class to draw a shooter cannon

2. shooter and cannon--> shooter class draws a shooter in game and cannon is the object of it used by gameview class
3. paint is the name of the identifier used to paint cannon in shooter class

GAMEVIEW CLASS

```
//Package and Import

public class GameView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnTouchListener{
    //some code to declare variables used 
    shooter cannon;
    Timer timer;
int time ,startTime=6000;//6000 milisec
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        timer = new Timer();
        time = (int)(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()*startTime);
        cannon = new shooter(Color.BLUE, mContext);
        addView(cannon);
        cannon.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //Some code to call cannon.move(); function onTouch and some other code
        return true;
    }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw (final Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            time = (int)(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()*startTime);
            drawGameBoard(canvas);

            try {

                Thread.sleep(1);

            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
// what sort algorithm I have to use to change its color after every 6000 milisec (please be little bit detailed)

            if(time%6000==0) {

                if(cannon.paint.getColor()==Color.RED) {
                    cannon.paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                }
                else { cannon.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                     }

        }
            invalidate();
    }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged ( int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            width = w;height = h;
            aliens.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
                bullets.get(i).setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

            }
        }
        public void drawGameBoard (Canvas canvas){

            cannon.draw(canvas);
            for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (bullets.get(i) != null) {
                    bullets.get(i).draw(canvas);

                    if (bullets.get(i).move()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    bullets.remove(i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = explosions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (explosions.get(i) != null) {
                    if (!explosions.get(i).draw(canvas)) {
                        explosions.remove(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (aliens != null) {
                aliens.draw(canvas);

                RectF guyRect = aliens.getRect();

                for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                    if (RectF.intersects(guyRect, bullets.get(i).getRect())) {
                        explosions.add(new explosion(Color.RED, mContext, aliens.getX() , aliens.getY()));
                        score+=10;
                        aliens.reset();
                        bullets.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (aliens.move()) {

                    return;
                }
                aliens = null;

            }
        }
        // Whenever the user shoots a bullet, create a new bullet moving upwards
        public void shootCannon () {
           //some code to shootCannon (StackOverflow)
        }
    }
```

Here's Shooter Class(cannon is object of this class) may be useful in any way

```
//package and Imports
public class shooter extends View  {

        public Paint paint;
    Point center;
    int left,right,cW,cH,i=0,shootPoint,top;
        public shooter(int color, Context c) {
            super(c);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(color);
        }
        public void move() {
            if(left==0)
            {
                left=center.x;
                right=cW;
                shootPoint=left+(left/2);
            }
            else
            {
                left=0;
                right=center.x;
                shootPoint=right/2;
            }
            invalidate();
        }
        public float getPosition()
        {
            return shootPoint;
        }
        public int shooterY(){ return (int)top;}
        public void draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.draw(canvas);
            //some code here to initiate left,top,right 
            canvas.drawCircle(shootPoint,top+5,cW/4,paint);
            canvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,paint);
        }
    }
```

If still there's something not understood please let me know

Feel free to say no but please try to answer it in detail as I am new to GUI based programming

Comment: Calling `invalidate()` (and, in most cases, calling `setColor()`) is only permissible on the UI thread. When you use a `Timer`, you're not using the UI thread; you're using a background thread. Also, you're creating a ton of `TimerTasks` (one for each invocation of `onDraw()`); that's just gonna make a mess. I would recommend you just take a time hack at game start (`startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`) and just call that periodically, inside  `onDraw()`, to determine when 4 seconds have elapsed.

Comment: Going to try SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() rather but it actually work only when I move the cannon and it's redrawn at different coordinates . Please let it be little bit more detailed... I didn't get you perfectly..

Comment: You've got the rest of it right; you call `setColor()`, then call `invalidate()`, and boom - your cannon is the new color (beginning at the next scheduled screen refresh). That's all there is to it. Don't use `Timer`, and take care to execute your logic on the UI thread. Use `Log.d()` and logcat to ensure your logic is executing only once every 4 seconds.

Comment: Please don't mind but I am still confused cause, it didn't work periodically anyway means at every 4 second. Although thanks greeble if this is your real name..

Comment: OK edit your question to include your new code and let me know and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: sorry for responding to late @greeble31  I have edited my silly algorithm for solving a complicated problem ... Can you tell me how much wrong I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it -- try to think of it more in terms of a "elapsed time".

In the GameView constructor, change it to this:

```
...
timer = new Timer();
startTime = (int)SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
...
```

In `onDraw()`, change it to this:

```
...
super.onDraw(canvas);
int elapsedTime = (int)(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime);
//elapsedTime is now the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since startTime.
drawGameBoard(canvas);

if((elapsedTime/6000)%2==0) {    //True for 0-5999, false for 6000-11999, true for 12000-17999, etc.
    if(cannon.paint.getColor()!=Color.BLUE) {
        cannon.paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        cannon.invalidate();
    }
}
else {
    if(cannon.paint.getColor()!=Color.RED) {
        cannon.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        cannon.invalidate();
    }
}

invalidate();    //prompt a re-draw of this GameView (gameboard)
...
```

It's also better to do the time math using `longs` instead of `ints`, but you can do that yourself.

And that `sleep()` in `onDraw()` doesn't do anything useful, so I took it out.

Comment: Hii @greeble31 again I stuck in a problem cause of my less experience with Android.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60140376/12264382. Here is all details if you can please cause still there are zero answers..